# WebApi and WinForms and Serial port with error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with a webapi class and an application in Win Forms. A Win Forms application has a class to access the serial port. This class has been initialized in the main application.

The error that occurs is: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

The steps are as follows:
The webapi receives the command and sends the data to the MainForm. The MainForm should send to the serial port, but I'm not getting. The reported error occurs.

The sources are below:

WebApi event:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ExecutarComando([FromBody]string comando)        
{
    TCCWindows.FormPrincipal.EnviarComandoWeb(comando);
}
```

Program:

```
public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
{       
    SerialPort spSimulador = new SerialPort();        
    PortaSerial spSistema = new PortaSerial();

    HttpSelfHostServer server;

    private Bitmap image = null;
    private Bitmap image2 = null;
    private float angle = 0.0f;
    private float angle2 = 0.0f;
    public static string LatitudeGD, LongitudeGD;
    ....
    ....
    public static void EnviarComandoWeb(string comando)
    {
        spSistema.EnviarComandoWeb(comando);
    }

}
```

Problem in:

```
public static void EnviarComandoWeb(string comando)
{
    spSistema.EnviarComandoWeb(comando);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you accessing non static `PortaSerial spSistema` 
through static member `EnviarComandoWeb`

This

```
PortaSerial spSistema = new PortaSerial();
```

didn't run when you trying to do this

```
spSistema.EnviarComandoWeb(comando);
```

You just can't do it. Must not do it. In other words, you shouldn't expect that when you access a static method, a whole class will be initialized. You can use only static members from static methods.